# Apache Ignite IGFS Not using Non Heap Space

Tags: java, performance, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite 2.6.  I am using Ignite Filesystem, and when I write a specific file, which is about 25 MB, to IGFS, over and over, the data is not saved into the non-heap space.  Instead, it goes into heap, which is subject to Garbage Collection, and it is relatively slow.  How do I get IGFS to save a file into the large heap space I have allocated for it?

High level architecture--I have a client ignite node running inside of a tomcat for now, and a server ignite node, on which I intend this data to be stored.  Scaling can occur once I get this working as expected--but it is very slow because of the aforementioned problem.  It also OOMs when it runs out of heap space very quickly.  Thing is, I want it to use the 30G of NON HEAP space I have allocated!

I intend this it to be an **in memory** cache. I am allocating 2 G of heap space and 30G of non heap space to the JVM.  The non heap space never gets used and it runs out of memory as a result.  I have confirmed that the non-heap space is not used using the JMX Console Memory tab--non heap space stays well below 100M, while heap space quickly balloons to 2G and then the JVM crashes.

The details:  First, my ignite configuration (spring xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="marshaller">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller" />
    </property>

    <property name="fileSystemConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.FileSystemConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="igfs"/>
                <property name="blockSize" value="#{128 * 1024}"/>
                <property name="perNodeBatchSize" value="512"/>
                <property name="perNodeParallelBatchCount" value="16"/>
                <property name="prefetchBlocks" value="32"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration" >
            <!-- if I don't set this, the system region runs out of memory almost immediately -->
            <property name="systemRegionMaxSize" value="#{6L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024"} />
            <property name="systemRegionInitialSize" value="#{6L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024"} />
        </bean>

    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the script I use to start up my ignite server process.  It's a shell script running on a Linux machine with 64 G RAM and 40 G disk space.

```
IGNITE_HOME=/data/apache-ignite
export IGNITE_HOME
IGNITE_JMX_PORT=1234
export IGNITE_JMX_PORT
$IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.sh $IGNITE_HOME/ignite-media-server.xml -J-Xmx2G -J-Xms2G -J-XX::+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -J-XX:HeapDumpPath=$IGNITE_HOME -J-XX:+PrintGC -J-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -J-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -J-Xloggc:$IGNITE_HOME/gc.log-$(date +%m%d-%H%M%S) -J-XX:+UseG1GC -J-XX:DisableExplicitGC -J-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=30G
```

This is the code that creates my client igfs object, through which I save files to ignite. They tend to be on the large side.

```
public void init() throws Exception{
    igniteInstanceName = "client-name=" + hostInfo.getLocalHost();
    Ignition.setClientMode(true); 
    // reading in the same config file as the server uses to start up above.  The big difference is the clientMode set to true here. 
    try(InputStream configFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("ignite-media-server.xml"));){
         ignite = IgnitionEx.start(configFileInputStream, igniteInstanceName, null, null);
         igfs = ignite.fileSystem("igfs");

    }
    catch(Throwable t){ /* do log */}

}
```

Here is a save method, that saves my files to ignite:

```
public saveStream(String cachePath, AudioInputStream toCache){
   OutputStream os = null;
   try{
       IgfsPath cacheFile = new IgfsPath(cachePath);
       os = igfs.create(cacheFile, true);
       AudioSystem.write(toCache.getDataStream, AudioFileFormat.TYPE.WAVE, os);
   }
   finally{
      // close streams
   }
}
```

Why doesn't my data get saved to the speedy off-heap space?  What am I missing?  my server.config comes almost straight from the igfs provided example.

In other confusion, when I use ignitevisor.cmd to inspect memory usage on the server node before and after a shorter test (that doesn't make it crash) I see the following:

Look at memory allocation while ignite is empty in ignitevisor.cmd. See that my igfs region says:

- Heap Memory Initialized: 2g
- Heap Memory Used: 56mb
- Non-heap memory initialized: 2mb
- Non Heap memory used: 49 mb
- Non heap memory maximum: 744mb

Create JUST SHY 2 G worth of files saved in IGFS--just short of an OOM since from bitter experience I know it will blow up shortly. Use ignitevisor.cmd to look at the memory allocation of the nodes. This is what ... – MeowCode 2 mins ago

- Heap memory initialized: 2gb
- Heap memory used: 1gb
- Non Heap memory used 64 MB
- Non heap memory maximum: 744mb

Why is there still almost nothing in non-heap? And why does ignitevisor think that the non-heap maximum is 744 MB when it should be 30 GB?

In other points of interest, if I increase my heap size to 6 GB, it runs longer, but still the server crashes with an "OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space".  Interestingly, I can reproduce this even when I enable disk persistence.  Inspecting the heap dump file reveals a lot of ConcurrentLinkedHashMap entries. The entries themselves are "org.apache.ignite.internal.GridTopic" objects. Each one has a uuid and most appear to be of type TOPIC_DATASTREAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is saved to Off-Heap all right, but you should be aware that a lot of transient objects involved in IGFS operation will still be briefly held on heap (and GCed after that).

"JMX Console Memory tab--non heap space" is the wrong metric. I don't think that there are any JVM metrics for Off-Heap. However, Ignite will print Off-Heap statistics at regular intervals.

Why you would run out of memory is not obvious. Have you tried collecting heap dump and analyzing it?

Comment: let me outline the test in more detail.  
1.  Allocate 2 G of Heap, 30 G of non-heap.  Do not enable persistence.  
2.  Look at memory allocation while ignite is empty in ignitevisor.cmd.  See that my igfs region says: Heap Memory Initialized:  2g/Heap Memory Used: 56mb Non-heap memory initialized: 2mb / Non Heap memory used: 49 mb / Non heap memory maximum: 744mb  
2.  Create JUST SHY 2 G worth of files saved in IGFS--just short of an OOM since from bitter experience I know it will blow up shortly.
3.  Use ignitevisor.cmd to look at the memory allocation of the nodes.  This is what ...

Comment: Now after the test, ignitevisor says:  Heap memory initialized: 2gb / Heap memory used: 1gb  / Non Heap memory used 64 MB

Why is there still almost nothing in non-heap?  And why does ignitevisor think that the non-heap maximum is 744 MB when it should be 30 GB?

Comment: I added this comment to the bottom of the main ticket, since it is too hard to read this text in the comment formats.  It will be easier for you to read it there.  Thank you for discussing with me!

Comment: As I have already said you should ignore "Non Heap" metrics since they measure entirely different thing.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand.  What metric should I look at to tell what is happening in my memory allocation?  The ignite logs that are produced every two seconds say more or less the same thing as the ignitevisor.cmd.

Comment: Heap dump inspection tells me that almost all the size of the heap is ConcurrentLinkedHashMap entries.  The entries themselves are "org.apache.ignite.internal.GridTopic" objects.  Each one has a uuid and most appear to be of type TOPIC_DATASTREAM.  My first guess is that it is the stream data I wrote in with igfs.

Comment: I guess that you fail to close DataStreamer's, hence objects that wait endlessly. Make sure you always close DataStreamer after doing data load.

Comment: I see some improvement, thank you.  I think part of the issue is also that it runs out of memory in the system partition, so I increased that again.  Perhaps that is due to the stream close problem.

Comment: It stopped running out of memory!  It's still slow though, will be working through that now.